# Vue Devtools Not Loading With Vue Electron Builder

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron

I'm creating an Electron / Vue application, and I cannot get the Vue Devtools to load in the Electron app window. This is my first time using Electron with Vue, and I'm not sure if there's a dependency issue that I'm not aware of.

I came across [this](https://github.com/nklayman/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/issues/909) Github issue, but my versions of Electron and `vue-cli-plugin-electron` are higher, and already include the updated code that is being discussed.

I also tried the following snippet (from [here](https://gist.github.com/ton77v/25108a7d7c0da7c98c7e45cbaabf76f5)):

```js
win.loadURL(process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_URL).then(() => {
  if (!process.env.IS_TEST) {
    setTimeout(() => win.webContents.openDevTools(), 5555)
  }
})
```

That caused everything to break.

The last major thing I tried was to use `vue invoke electron-builder` to reinvoke the generator, which was suggested in the [docs](https://nklayman.github.io/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/guide/commonIssues.html#exceptions-in-async-functions-not-getting-logged-to-console)

However the problem still persists. Can someone take a look at my setup and let me know if there's something obviously wrong?

Here is part of my `package.json`:

```json
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "dev": "npm run electron:serve",
    "electron:build": "vue-cli-service electron:build",
    "electron:serve": "vue-cli-service electron:serve",
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
    "postuninstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "main": "background.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat": "^2.0.2",
    "autoprefixer": "^9",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "electron": "^12.0.5",
    "jsstore": "^3.13.6",
    "postcss": "^7",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.0.2",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.0-0",
    "vuex": "^4.0.0-0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "^4.5.12",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "^4.5.12",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "electron": "^11.0.0",
    "electron-devtools-installer": "^3.2.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder": "~2.0.0-rc.6",
    "vue-cli-plugin-tailwind": "~2.0.6"
  }
```

And here is my `background.js` file:

```js
"use strict";

import { app, protocol, BrowserWindow } from "electron";
import { createProtocol } from "vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/lib";
import installExtension, { VUEJS_DEVTOOLS } from "electron-devtools-installer";
const isDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";

let win;
// Scheme must be registered before the app is ready
protocol.registerSchemesAsPrivileged([
  { scheme: "app", privileges: { secure: true, standard: true } },
]);

function createWindow() {
  // Create the browser window.
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      // Use pluginOptions.nodeIntegration, leave this alone
      // See nklayman.github.io/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/guide/security.html#node-integration for more info
      nodeIntegration: process.env.ELECTRON_NODE_INTEGRATION,
    },
  });

  if (process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_URL) {
    // Load the url of the dev server if in development mode
    win.loadURL(process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_URL);
    if (!process.env.IS_TEST) win.webContents.openDevTools();
  } else {
    createProtocol("app");
    // Load the index.html when not in development
    win.loadURL("app://./index.html");
  }
}

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
  // On macOS it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on("activate", () => {
  // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow();
});

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on("ready", async () => {
  if (isDevelopment && !process.env.IS_TEST) {
    // Install Vue Devtools
    try {
      await installExtension(VUEJS_DEVTOOLS);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error("Vue Devtools failed to install:", e.toString());
    }
  }
  createWindow();
});

// Exit cleanly on request from parent process in development mode.
if (isDevelopment) {
  if (process.platform === "win32") {
    process.on("message", (data) => {
      if (data === "graceful-exit") {
        app.quit();
      }
    });
  } else {
    process.on("SIGTERM", () => {
      app.quit();
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The production version of Vue DevTools doesn't support Vue 3 yet.

In order to workaround this issue, you must install the **Vue DevTools Beta** instead.

Replace this:

```js
await installExtension(VUEJS_DEVTOOLS);
```

With this:

```js
await installExtension({
  id: 'ljjemllljcmogpfapbkkighbhhppjdbg',
  electron: '>=1.2.1'
})
```

See the discussion [here](https://github.com/nklayman/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/issues/776#issuecomment-716088606).

#### UPDATE

You can now also just use the `VUEJS3_DEVTOOLS` constant like so:

```js
await installExtension(VUEJS3_DEVTOOLS);
```

Comment: It is enough to just change it to VUEJS3_DEVTOOLS. No need for id.

Comment: I guess that at the time I found this solution there hasn't a preset constant for Vue Devtools Beta :)

Comment: At this time, VUEJS3_DEVTOOLS is no longer working for me unless the extension has already been cached by electron. The preset points to an extension ID that is no longer available. I can now use the VUEJS_DEVTOOLS preset extension with Vue.js v3.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use timeouts, wait for the `dom-ready` event instead. I imagine setting it up like this will get everything to work.

[Related fix for Redux devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67207102/1837080).

```js
const {
    app,
    BrowserWindow,
} = require("electron");
const {
    default: installExtension,
    VUEJS_DEVTOOLS
} = require("electron-devtools-installer");
const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV === "development";

// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let win;

async function createWindow() {

    // Create the browser window.
    win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        title: "MyAppTitle",
        webPreferences: {
            devTools: isDev
        }
    });

    // Load app
    win.loadURL("index.html");

    // Only do these things when in development
    if (isDev) {

        // Errors are thrown if the dev tools are opened
        // before the DOM is ready
        win.webContents.once("dom-ready", async () => {
            await installExtension([VUEJS_DEVTOOLS])
                .then((name) => console.log(`Added Extension:  ${name}`))
                .catch((err) => console.log("An error occurred: ", err))
                .finally(() => {
                    win.webContents.openDevTools();
                });
        });
    }

    // Emitted when the window is closed.
    win.on("closed", () => {
        // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
        // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
        // when you should delete the corresponding element.
        win = null;
    });
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on("ready", createWindow);

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
    // On macOS it is common for applications and their menu bar
    // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
    if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
        app.quit();
    }
});
```